# FNF: Not able to execute ssh-base.sh

Tags: hadoop, ssh, oozie, oozie-coordinator

Trying to run a Oozie workflow but keep getting the following error message:

org.apache.oozie.action.ActionExecutorException: FNF: Not able to execute ssh-base.sh on username@servername | ErrorStream: *************************************************************************
          This machine is the property of xyz....

(Note:  I've setup passpharase-less access.  If I run the steps manually it works, but when I run thru Oozie it doesn't. In other words, I can login to the machine as user 'oozie', then ssh username@servername (without entering password) & then run the 'command'.  This works, but the Oozie workflow doesn't)

Here's my workflow.xml

```
<workflow-app name="my app" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.2">
    <start to="sshAction"/>
    <action name="sshAction">
        <ssh xmlns="uri:oozie:ssh-action:0.1">
            <host>username@servername</host>
            <command>cd /export/home/user/test/bin;./test.sh --arg value</command>
            <capture-output/>
        </ssh>
        <ok to="sendEmail"/>
        <error to="sendEmail" />
    </action>
    <action name="sendEmail">
        <email xmlns="uri:oozie:email-action:0.1">
              <to>username@xyz.com</to>
              <subject>Output of workflow ${wf:id()}</subject>
              <body>Status of the file move: ${wf:actionData('sshAction')['STATUS']}</body>
        </email>
        <ok to="end"/>
        <error to="end"/>
    </action>
    <end name="end"/>
 </workflow-app>
```

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19272430/oozie-ssh-action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out what was wrong by looking at the code.  FNF stands for 'File not found'.  It appears the 'ssh action' doesn't handle commands separated by semi-colon such as this:

cd /export/home/user/test/bin;./test.sh --arg value

Here's what I did:

1)  Changed the command to:

./test.sh --arg value

2)  Copied test.sh to the root directory of the user.

3)  Added cd /export/home/user/test/bin to the beginning of the 'test.sh'

It's working now!